# Two <div>'s stick together scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, contenteditable

I'm working on my diploma thesis, an interactive programming language which should run in browser eniroment using javascript.

In the moment I use an input line and enter event to start interaction and give feedback.
I would like to change this to have a textinput and a second field next to it where the result is shown. I use

```
<div id = "code" conetenteditable="true"> </div>
<div id= "result"><div>
```

Both are placed in a table row, so they are next to each other
how can I get result to scroll according to the actual scroll of code?

By the way I use jquery as library.

Thanks,

Rainer

Comment: i didn't undestand well what you achieve man...a row of a table has two divs...the second div has the answer...and you wanna scroll result? like a srollbar?

Answer (score 1):

In order for an element to be fixed on a page and remain there as you scroll, you must use CSS.

The code should look like:

```
<div id = "code" conetenteditable="true" style="position:fixed;"> </div>
<div id= "result" style="position:fixed"><div>
```

You can position them however you want with `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right`.

Answer (score 0):

Use css fixed position for your both dives.
like that:

```
#id,#result{
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is not with the element position but with the scroll of the text inside of the #result div.

If that's the case, you might want to use the overflow css property to have the div show an inner scrollbar.

```
#result {
    overflow-y:auto;
    max-height:100px;
}
```

in this example, the div will scroll if the text inside it stretches above 100px.